# What is the proper PHP response to a Slack `dialog_submisson` action?

Tags: php, slack-api

When there are no errors in the user's input, Slack requires a `200 OK` response and an empty `body`.

I've tried various combinations of responses, including:

```
http_response_code(200);
header ('Content-Type: text/plain');
exit("");
```

and:

```
http_response_code(200);
exit();
```

and:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
exit("");
```

But, the user's dialog **always** says:

```
"We had some trouble connecting. Try again?"
```

**Note: when I send an error using JSON, the dialog displays as expected.**

[image]

Comment: Sending no response and just exiting with `exit()` should work fine. You don't need set any header or HTTP response code. Those are set implicitly. You may want to check there is no other output in your script, e.g. an echo somewhere.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Thanks for the tip, but I just tried it and still the same result. I've searched for an example of PHP `dialog_submission`, but haven't found one yet.

Comment: I would post one of mine, but they use a lot of proprietary classes. Would not really help I think. However, they all just end the script normally, nothing special set or echo'd.

Comment: how about you add the relevant part of your code to the questions. That usually help a lot in finding the root cause.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, thanks that kind of led me in the right direction. As I was preparing the code sample, I eliminated included files, and voilà!

Comment: Awesome. Yeah those PHP closing tags at end of script files can often mess things up. It's why many people don't use them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header` was not the issue. As @ErikKalkoken mentioned in a comment, a simple `exit()` is appropriate. The issue was an included file had two returns after the closing tag. Like so:[image]

Interestingly, a single return does not trip up the Slack API.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, though only on certain scenarios when updating modals.

The answer boiled down to me wanting to track success/fail on the send and I was returning a message back to my other functions.

```
if (!empty($route)) {
    $slack_response = json_decode(curlslack($route, $body, '', false, $token));
    if (!empty($slack_response)) {
            $return = ['error' => false, 'message' => "Slack Message Sent", "slack_response" => $slack_response];
        }
    }
}
exit(); //********  This fixed the issue (though I could just as soon removed the return below.....)
//NOTE: we CANNOT return data here!  Slack requires an EMPTY message - and enforces it only on some scenarios.....
return json_encode($return);
```

I'll put a different bit of code in my app to return the data and only print it when I need it (for user verification), but not allow it when it comes from Slack, though I thought it might be helpful for others to see this is certainly something you need to pay attention to - do not send anything back to Slack!